# MySQL GROUP by Regex?

Tags: mysql, regex, database, group-by

I have the following query

```
SELECT Count(*) as Total_Count, Col1 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY Col1 
ORDER BY Total_Count DESC;
```

I want to zoom in on Col1. The data in Col1 are in the following format:

```
text-abc1
txt4-abcde22
tex6-abc2
text4-imp4
text-efg1
txt-efg43
```

I want to be able to group it by

```
After the first `-`, any first three/four/five characters match
```

In this example, if we match with first 3 characters. Output will be:

```
Total_Count   Col1
3             abc
1             imp
2             efg
```

Any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might not need a regex, just string operations. For three characters:

```
SELECT count(*) AS Total_Count,
SUBSTRING(Col1 FROM POSITION('-' in Col1)+1 FOR 3) AS Col1_zoomed
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Col1_zoomed
ORDER BY Total_Count DESC
```

Comment: This is the right one. Thanks for it. But `abcd-1234` needs to be `Col1`. Please change it so I can accept it :).

Comment: @daking963 As if this answer doesn't help you when one thing is spelled differently? Picky, picky! :-p

Comment: @Wiseguy It's not about being picky. It's for the correctness of the answer and a future reference for others. I am sure they can figure it out that instead of the string it should be the column name. It's just a typo, Ian can change it easily. To improve the overall quality of the site, in my opinion, these little things matter a lot!

Comment: Done :) Sorry, it was my sample data from shell-testing

Answer (score 4):

```
select
substring(substring_index(col1,'-',-1),1,3) as grp,
count(*) as total
from table
group by grp
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.

```
SELECT Count(*) as Total_Count, SUBSTRING(Col1, 1, 3)
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Col1, 1, 3) 
ORDER BY Total_Count DESC;
```

Comment: `SUBSTRING(Col1, 1, 3)` won't work in this case as I need to match characters after the `-`. Before the `-` there could be any number of characters.

Comment: I misread your question - I thought you wanted the first 3. Ian's answer is better then

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to answer the question "MySQL GROUP by Regex?" as the answers here address the problem provided.

You can group by REGEXP with the REGEXP_SUBSTR() function.

> REGEXP_SUBSTR(expr, pat[, pos[, occurrence[, match_type]]])
>
> Returns the substring of the string expr that matches the regular
> expression specified by the pattern pat, NULL if there is no match. If
> expr or pat is NULL, the return value is NULL.

For example:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(YOUR_COLUMN, 'YOUR REGEXP');
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Count(*) as Total_Count, Col1, REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col1, '[a-z0-9]*', 0, 2) as Col1_combined 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(Col1, '[a-z0-9]*', 0, 2) 
ORDER BY Total_Count DESC;
```

`REGEXP_SUBSTR` returns the string matching the given regular expression `[a-z0-9]` starting from position `0` in text and return the `2` occurrence. Documentation for [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr)

`REGEXP_SUBSTR(<column_name>, <regular_expression>, <starting_position>, <match_occurrence>)`