# Group MySQL search by REGEX for IP Addresses

Tags: mysql, regex, database, group-by

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273405/mysql-group-by-regex) in regards to grouping a MySQL search by a pattern, but I'm in need of doing this for IP addresses.  I need to group IP addresses by the first 3 octets, but I don't quite see how to accompish this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you are trying to achieve? Do you want just a list of unique first 3 octets, or are you after something else?

Comment: @Tim - yes, a list of the first 3 octets for all IP address along with a count of each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MySQL SUBSTRING_INDEX function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) might be useful here:

```
drop table if exists test_ip;

create table test_ip
(id int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
ip varchar(50) not null,
UNIQUE KEY test_ip_uidx1 (ip));

insert into test_ip (ip) values ('24.21.114.4');
insert into test_ip (ip) values ('24.21.114.5');
insert into test_ip (ip) values ('24.21.114.6');
insert into test_ip (ip) values ('24.21.115.6');
insert into test_ip (ip) values ('24.21.115.7');
insert into test_ip (ip) values ('24.21.115.8');
insert into test_ip (ip) values ('24.21.116.1');

select substring_index(ti.ip,'.',3) as firstThreeOctet,count(*) as ipCount
from test_ip ti
group by substring_index(ti.ip,'.',3);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sweet!  You are a god amongst men for this MySQL n00b!